# Set descending table sorting order in Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I can not figure out how to make it so that when user clicks the header the first time it sorts it in descending order rather than ascending, instead of the user having to click twice to have it sorted in descending.

```
$('#my_table').tablesorter(
    {
        //code to sort descending order first
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortInitialOrder` from the [docs](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Configuration) will work.

You should be able to use like this

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    sortInitialOrder: 'desc'
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using the unofficial forked version, rather the vanilla tablesorter and do not have the opportunity to choose which. In the vanilla docs there is a forceSort option but I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @nyvokub can you provide a link to which version you're using?

Comment: Sure thing - http://tablesorter.com/docs/. There is some sortForce option but it is not doing what I intend and the example in the docs seems incorrect/broken.

Comment: @nyvokub not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish. Can you create a jsfiddle/codepen demonstrating the issue & provide link?

Comment: I scrapped the idea. I'm going to mark your answer as correct since it is correct for the forked version.